# Changing GNAT runtime name

Tags: runtime, ada

I am building my own Ada runtime system.

However, I can only link again the custom runtime if it is called 'gnat' and compiled to 'libgnat.a' If I call it anything else I get the ld error:

/home/mark/opt/GNAT/2021/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.1/ld: cannot find -lgnat

Any ideas on how to configure this so I can use a different name?

Here's the project file for the runtime (most of it is from OSdev)

```
project milo is
   
  for Languages use ("Ada");
  for Runtime ("Ada") use Project'Project_Dir;
  
  for Library_Auto_Init use "False";
  for Library_Name use "milo"; -- that must be "gnat"
  for Library_Kind use "static";

  for Library_Dir use "lib";
  for Object_Dir use "obj";
  for Source_Dirs use ("src/zfp", "src/milo");

   package Builder is
      for Global_Configuration_Pragmas use "milo.adc";
      for Switches ("Ada") use (
        "-nostdlib",
        "-nostdinc"
      );
   end Builder;

  package Compiler is
      for Default_Switches ("Ada") use (
        "-O2",
        "-ffunction-sections", 
        "-fdata-sections",
        "-fcallgraph-info=su,da",
        "-gnatp",
        "-gnatn2",                           
        "-gnat2012",
        "-gnatg",
        "-Wl,--gc-sections",
        "-gnatyN"
      );
   end Compiler;

end milo;
```

And here's the project that I am trying to use this runtime with

```
project Helloworld is

   for Source_Dirs use ("src");
   for Object_Dir use "obj";
   for Main use ("helloworld.adb");
   for Runtime ("ada") use "/home/mark/Milo/milo/";

end Helloworld;
```

Comment: I don't see a Linker package in the gpr file, but I would expect that would be where different library names were used. (You may also look into how e.g. the AVR-Ada project does its own RTS ... or my old MSP430 project https://sourceforge.net/projects/msp430ada/

Comment: Looks like you can specify the runtime library under the RTS_LIB_LIST setting in a makefile. I really was hoping to avoid makefiles!

Answer (score 3):

See [here](https://github.com/simonjwright/cortex-gnat-rts/tree/master/stm32f4) for an example of a runtime whose name is `stm32f4`, for the Cortex M4F-based STM32F4 MCU from STMicroelectronics.

To be a runtime called `milo`, the structure has to be at least

```
$prefix/milo/adainclude
            |
            /adalib
```

where `adainclude/` holds the source files and `adalib/` holds the `.ali` files and the library (usually `libgnat.a`, because it's hidden from users).

If that's all, then GNAT will be happy with `gprbuild --RTS=$prefix/milo`. But in may cases you'll want to alter how the compiler deals with Ada options and the linker commands. This is the job of the file `runtime.xml`, which is a gprbuild configuration file.

In package `Compiler`, see

```
      Common_Required_Switches :=
         ("-mlittle-endian", "-mhard-float",
          "-mcpu=cortex-m4", "-mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16", "-mthumb");
```

for switches appropriate for the target processor which will be applied to every compilation using this runtime (you might say, what about `-ffunction-sections` and `-fdata-sections`, and I wouldn't have a good answer for you!)

In package `Linker`, see

```
      for Required_Switches use Linker'Required_Switches &amp;
        ("${RUNTIME_DIR(ada)}/adalib/libgnat.a") &amp;
        Compiler.Common_Required_Switches &amp;
        ("-nostdlib", "-lm", "-lgcc", "-lc");

      for Required_Switches use Linker'Required_Switches &amp;
        ("-T", "${RUNTIME_DIR(ada)}/adalib/stm32f407-flash.ld");
```

of which the first part tells the linker to use `$prefix/milo/adalib/libgnat.a`, and the second (which could have been concatenated with the first, now I come to look at it) tells the linker script to use instead of the one baked into the compiler.

I think a useul addition here would be `--gc-sections`.

The `&amp;`s are there because this is an XML file, and `&` needs escaping.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up cheating, and created a symbolic link

> ln -s libmilo.a libgnat.a

If there's a better way, please post!